# WebRTC through host with nodeJS express and socketio

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc, streaming

I created a web app to let people communicate. I want to implement screen sharing and audio calls.

My current app is programmed in NodeJs and uses express and socket.io to serve the client connection and open a socket connection. I want to stream video and audio. My problem with WebRTC is that all those who connect to a call are vulnerable to a DDoS attack since it is p2p. I found an article from Discord explaining how they managed to let the entire traffic go through their servers: https://blog.discord.com/how-discord-handles-two-and-half-million-concurrent-voice-users-using-webrtc-ce01c3187429, that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Could I possibly use socket.io-stream https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream ? I didn't yet figure out how, and it seems like all socket.io streaming libraries are made for file upload/download, not for actual video/audio streaming.

If that doesn't work, a library such as what Discord managed to make would be the perfect solution, since all traffic is proxied, and not p2p. Though I couldn't find any of those libraries, maybe I'm just looking for the wrong thing?
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/).

Each peer negotiates a session with the SFU. They then exchange media through it. Each Peer will just communicate with the server. It has lots of other benefits and is what most WebRTC deploys today use.

There are lots of Open Source SFUs out there. You can even build your own with Open Source libraries.